# SEM PLS on R - plspm does not install

Tags: r, pls

I need to run SEM (with PLS) analysis, and was provided script that is used the plspm package.
I tried to install but it says it's no longer available for current R update.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘plspm’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

Also on further investigation it's no longer stored on cran.

```
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plspm/index.html    
    Package ‘plspm’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
    Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
    Archived on 2020-05-14 as long orphaned and those depending on it have been given notice.
```

Should I install an older version of R to run this package?, and download plspm independently (outside cran)?
If plspm out of date is there a problem with using this package?
Is there a better package to run SEM with PLS?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the latest posts on here regarding PLS SEM, there seems to be a package called semPLS which might work. I have just managed to install it on the latest version of R, but have not yet tried it out.